# Calculating the second derivative of $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}\mapsto M^5$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> If $f:\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is given by $f(M)=M^5$, find $D^2f(X)(H,K)$ for $X,H,K\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

I know how to find $D^1f(X)(H)$ by doing:
\begin{align*}
D^1f(X)(H)&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(X+tH)-f(X)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(X+tH)^5-X^5}{t}\\
&=X^4H+X^3HX+X^2HX^2+XHX^3+HX^4
\end{align*}

But when I try to do a similar computation for $D^1f$, namely $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{D^1f(X+tH)-D^1f(X)}{t}$, I get confused with the meaning of the limit.

I guess my confusion is that $D^1f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ to $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m\times m})$ (linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ to itself), and I don't know how to deal with $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m\times m})$ when it comes to derivation.

Comment: Do all your matrices commute?  You should be very careful about combining terms.

Comment: @MichaelBurr that's precisely the problem. What's the right way approach this then?

Comment: Don't combine terms.  Just write it out.  For example, the $(X+tH)^4$ would be $X^4+tX^3H+tX^2HX+tXHX^2+tHX^3+\dots$.  (All other terms don't matter for this derivative).  Make sure that you check your original derivative as well - you combined terms in $D^1f(X)(H)$, so that's not right either.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've made a correction for $D^1f(X)(H)$, is this correct now?

Comment: That looks better (except the exponent on the last $X$).

Comment: Do you have a definition for $D^2$ (or $D^n$)?  There are various ways to define this and some might use notation that is quite confusing.

Comment: The definition of $D^2f$ I know is just the derivative of $D^1f:\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}\to\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m\times m})$, so $D^1f(X+H)-D^1f(X)=D^2f(X)(H)+r(H)$, with $\lim_{H\to 0}\frac{r(H)}{|H|}=0$. But that confuses me, because I don't know how to plug $K$ in there.

Comment: Perhaps you want to keep $H$ as a constant and take the derivative of the $D^1f(X)(H)$ that you found before.  In other words, $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{D^1f(X+tK)(H)-D^1f(X)(H)}{t}.$$  There are other definitions that one could have for $D^2$ (e.g., in terms of differential forms), but I think this is what is intended here.

Comment: And what is the difference between doing what you did and this: $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{D^1f(X+tH)(K)-D^1f(X)(K)}{t}$$?

Comment: Try computing both (but being careful about the order of elements).  In some cases, there would be a sign difference between the two, depending on how things are calculated.  Here, the signs should be the same, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simpler case, let's try $f(M)=M^3$.  In this case,

\begin{align*}
D^1f(X)(H)&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(X+tH)-f(X)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{X^3+tX^2H+tXHX+tHX^2+t^2XH^2+t^2HXH+t^2H^2X+t^3H^3-X^3}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(X^2H+XHX+HX^2+tXH^2+tHXH+t2H^2X+t^2H^3)\\
&=X^2H+XHX+HX^2.
\end{align*}

Now, using the formula from above, we might consider
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}&\frac{D^1f(X+tK)(H)-D^1f(X)(H)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{(X+tK)^2H+(X+tK)H(X+tK)+H(X+tK)^2-(X^2H+XHX+HX^2)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{X^2H+tXKH+tKXH+t^2K^2H}{t}+\frac{XHX+tXHK+tKHX+t^2KHK}{t}+\frac{HX^2+tHXK+tHKX+t^2HK^2}{t}-\frac{X^2H+XHX+HX^2}{t}\right)\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(XKH+KXH+tK^2H+XHK+KHX+tKHK+HXK+HKX+tHK^2)\\
&=XKH+KXH+XHK+KHX+HXK+HKX
\end{align*}

If you follow the same procedure, but reversing the roles of $H$ and $K$, you'll get the same answer because the answer is symmetric in the roles of $H$ and $K$.  If I try to type it out, I'm sure that I'm going to make an error.  But the final answer is that *both* limits above give the same answer.